# DBT - Looping through the values in a column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jinja2, dbt

I have generated a column containing a distinct list of dates, and would like to turn this column into a list which I can iterate through via Jinja loops

Does anyone know how to achieve this, or an alternative method? All examples I have seen explicitly list out the variables in their list, e.g.

```
{% set animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse'] %}
```

However I want to use a dynamic list of dates, which would be updated as time goes on.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a query against your DB and load the results into your jinja context using the built-in [`run_query`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query) macro.

For your specific case, there is also a more convenient macro in dbt-utils called [`get_column_values`](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#get_column_values-source). You use it like this:

```sql
{% set animals = dbt_utils.get_column_values(
    table=ref("my_animal_model"), column="animal_names"
) %}
{% log(animals, info=true) %}
{% for animal in animals %}
    -- do something
{% endfor $}
```

You can also supply additional arguments to the macro to sort, filter, and limit the values.